# android How do I determine which permission(s) block my app from Google store?

Tags: android, android-permissions

My app currently not searchable from a Nexus 7.  I suspect that is because of one or more permissions I have set in the manifest, as it is available and downloads just fine on phones.

I can go through a cumbersome trial-and-error process of eliminating some permissions and posting to the alpha site, waiting for Google to propagate the APK, and trying to download.  After several tries, I should be able to determine the cause.

Is there an easier way?

Thanks.

Comment: Permissions won't block you from seeing it.  uses-feature statements can.  I'd look at those first.

Comment: Can you list the permissions in this question. Additionally search ability is affected by <uses feature> and compatible-screens, supports-screens tags too.

Comment: @GabeSechan - I was unaware of uses-feature and have been using uses-permission.  I'm reading about it now.  However, apparently uses-permission does block seeing the app in the store search.

Answer (score 0):

When a user searches or browses for apps to download on Google Play, the results are filtered based on which applications are compatible with the device.

Filtering in Google Play is based on several types of app metadata and configuration settings, including manifest declarations, required libraries,architecture dependencies, and distribution controls set in the Google Play Developer Console, such as geographic targeting, pricing, and more.

For more detailed information, see the [docs](http://developer.android.com/google/play/filters.html).